# Convert a count aggregate to comma format

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to add a conversion to a count aggregate and format with commas xx,xxx something like this...

```
  Convert(varchar, cast(count(aid) as Count_id ???
```

Any help with the syntax would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),COUNT(aid)) AS Count_id FROM [dbo.Yourtablename]
```

Replace table name in where clause with your table.
Hope it will work for you.

**For thousands comma seperator you can use this:**

```
select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, COUNT(aid)),1),'.00','') AS Count_id from [Yourtablename];
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant by comma format?? @Toby You want it be showed like 1,000 for thousand and 1,00,000 for lakh??

Comment: Sorry, I would like to see a comma in the format. Such as xx,xxx or xxx,xxx

Comment: @Toby I had updated my answer,check it. If it works for you mark it as correct and useful.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  CAST(count(aid) as VARCHAR(20)) aid.